# What does this gradient-like symbol mean?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, physics, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics

If $\nabla \phi$ denotes the gradient of some scalar field $\phi$,

then what does  $\nabla^2 (\phi^2)$ mean?  I don't think it means taking the gradient of a gradient (of a squared-scalar field), but I'm not sure what it could be.

It's part of a hint that I am supposed to use to show that a vector field $\vec F$ is identically zero in some convex region.

Thanks,

Comment: Usually that mean the [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator)

Comment: $\nabla^2$ is the Laplacian operator, $\nabla^2 \equiv \nabla \cdot \nabla$. Here you are taking the Laplacian of the square of the scalar field.

Comment: Hi @okrzysik -- interesting; so what you just showed is an inner product?  Specifically, a dot product in $R^3$ of two gradient vectors?  Thanks

Comment: @user290762 sure is!

Comment: Hi @JohnMa, why is $2 \nabla \phi . \nabla \phi = 2||F||$, where F is the gradient of phi?  How do we arrive at an operator norm?  Thanks,

Comment: It is on the solution, but I do not understand this line of reasoning @JohnMa ... thanks :-)

Comment: Oh, nevermind -- treating it as a vector norm, then it looks fine. But probably should be $||F||^2$ @JohnMa ...

Comment: @user290762 : I am not sure how you get $2 \nabla \phi \cdot \nabla \phi = 2\|\nabla \phi\|$. It should be $2\| \nabla \phi\|^2$ by definition.

Comment: yes, I think the solution is wrong ... thanks @JohnMa :-)

Comment: Hi @JohnMa -- the Laplacian symbol is also sometimes the right-side-up triangle, too, right (instead of the square of the upside-down triangle)?  I've seen that I think at least a little bit in complex variables on topics regarding harmonic functions.  If so...then there's two Laplacian symbols then...and possibly even more?  Thanks,

Comment: Hi @JohnMa, I now see that it is probably more 'insightful' to write the Laplacian in this way; then one can see the divergence of a gradient field (perhaps advantageous, when using the Divergence Theorem) -- and if the gradient field is known to be divergence-free, then the Laplacian reduces to $0$.  I have posted a proof of my work on a problem statement just now in a new question on MSE.  Please feel free to comment on it, if you have time :-)  Thanks so much,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator). I.e. $\nabla^2 f=\sum \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2} f$